# Doctrine ManyToMany - get one instance from JoinTable, not Collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have two entities: "A" and "B" and next requirements:

- one "A" related to zero or **many** of B (0-N, oneToMany);
- one "B" related to zero or **one** "A" (0-1, oneToOne nullable)

Join entity "AB" defined, but not used now, MySQL table "AB" used for joining "A" and "B":

```sql
CREATE TABLE `AB` (
  `id`   int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `A_id` int,
  `B_id` int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `A_id_B_id` (`A_id`, `B_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Next code works almost fine, but method "B:getAInstance()" returns Collection of "A":

```php
$b = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:B')->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);
Debug::dump($b->getInstance);
```

dumps next:

```php
array (size=1) 0 => 
    object(stdClass)[794]
      public '__CLASS__' => string 'My\Namespace\A' (length=35)
```

But i need only one or zero instances of "A", so, method must return instance of A or null.

I try to set-up another associations, with or without "AB" entity but I did not succeed. So, what changes need my code to meet the requirements (additional tables, entities, annotations etc)?

Weird solution is return `$this->aInstance[0]` but this is a way to problems.

In code below, unnecessary getters, setters and annotations are omitted.

Entity A:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="A")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class A
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection|A[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(
     *      targetEntity="B",
     *      cascade={"all"}
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *      name="AB",
     *      joinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *              name="B_id",
     *              referencedColumnName="id"
     *          )
     *      },
     *      inverseJoinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *              name="A_id",
     *              referencedColumnName="id"
     *          )
     *      }
     * )
     **/
    private $bList;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bList  = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

Entity B:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="B")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class B
{
    /**
     * @var A
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(
     *      targetEntity="A",
     *      cascade={"all"}
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *      name="AB",
     *      joinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *              name="A_id",
     *              referencedColumnName="id"
     *          )
     *      },
     *      inverseJoinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *              name="B_id",
     *              referencedColumnName="id"
     *          )
     *      }
     * )
     */
    private $aInstance;

    public function getAInstance()
    {
        return $this->aInstance;
    }
}
```

Entity AB:

```php
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="AB")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class AB
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="A_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $A_id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="B_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $B_id;
}
```

Comment: how can A -> B be one to many... wouldn't that automatically make B -> A Many to One?

Comment: No, because one "B" related to zero or one "A", NOT one or more "A".

Comment: ok so we have one A related to 2 Bs... B1 and B2 ...  so there are 2 B's now have the same A as the inverse?

Comment: Yes. B1 related to A, and B2 related to the same A. One day this relation can break, B1 and B2 forget about A, and A forget about B1 and B2.

A very simple example: Company (A) and Employee (B). 

Employee can be related to one and only one Company (as office staff) or be a freelancer without any relation to Company. At any time Employee can accept relation to Company, but also at any time Company can break this relation and Employee is going to odesk, but still working with Company on the same Project :)

Comment: if the employee is still working with the company on the project... there is still a relationship... you'd want to runt compnay.employees and get a list... on the other end you run comployee.company and you get the company... that will ALWAYS be ONE company ... however the relationship from B to A is just the inverse of what A to B is ... so i still dont see the point of having the oneToOne relationship... (to be honest i dont think its even possible)

Comment: "however the relationship from B to A is just the inverse of what A to B is ... so i still dont see the point of having the oneToOne relationship" - nope, the domain model says, that A **must** relate to (many) B, but B **can** relate to (one) A. Maybe i have a mistake in relation naming, please, correct me: A -> B is oneToMany, and B -> A is oneToOne? You says, that B -> A should be a manyToOne (inverse of A -> B), but, B **cant** has a **many** A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can solve your problem by using a [Bidirectional](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) OneToMany A -> B

ManyToOne B -> A means that Many Bs can share the same A... but it will guarantee that a B cannot have more than ONE A...

A -> B is oneToMany ... B -> A ManyToOne (inverse side) ... in this case.. A can have 0 or more Bs... you can also set the inverse side to be nullable in that case... B will not be aware of any As ...

Comment: "A one-to-many association has to be bidirectional, unless you are using an additional join-table." - but I have a join-table, see beginning of the question.